# Laravel hash::make and hash::check with auth class

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Trying to figure out how to use Laravel's Hash and Auth class in a login function. When my user registers, I use this:

```
$password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
```

The result is stored in the database table. In the login function, I want to check if password and email are valid, so I do this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'activated' => 1)))
```

But the password in Auth::attempt is plain text. What should I pass there for it to compare with the version stored in table (result of Hash::make()) previously.

Comment: Auth::attempt will automatically do the hashing for you. Just pass it the password (from input)

Comment: oh yes that worked. Want to add it as answer to be marked? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auth::attempt will automatically do the hashing for you. Just pass it the password (from input)